# Docker compose to have executed 'command: bash' and keep container open

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, yaml, playwright

The docker compose yml file below keeps the container open after I run `docker compose up -d` but `command: bash` does not get executed:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  service:
    container_name: pw-cont
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.30.0-focal
    stdin_open: true          # -i
    tty: true                 # -t
    network_mode: host        # --network host
    volumes:                  # Ensures that updates in local/container are in sync
      - $PWD:/playwright/
    working_dir: /playwright
    command: bash
```

After I spin the container up, I wanted to visit Docker Desktop > Running container's terminal.

**Expectation**: Since the file has `command: bash`, I expect that in  docker desktop, when I go to the running container's terminal, it will show `root@docker-desktop:/playwright#`.

**Actual**: Container's terminal in docker desktop is showing `#`, still need to type `bash` to see `root@docker-desktop:/playwright#`.

Can the yml file be updated so that `bash` gets auto executed when spinning up the container?

Answer (score 0):

`docker compose` doesn't provide that sort of interactive connection. Your `docker-compose.yaml` file is fine; once your container is running you can attach to it using `docker attach pw-cont` to access stdin/stdout for the container.

```
$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container pw-cont  Started                                                                       0.1s
$ docker attach pw-cont
root@rocket:/playwright#
root@rocket:/playwright#
```

Comment: I see, no wonder why I could not find any solution. Yeah, if I do a command like `docker attach pw-cont` / `docker exec -it pw-cont /bin/bash` in my IDE's terminal, it defaults to `root@docker-desktop:/playwright#`. This is true even without the `command: bash` in the yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but using the `run` command

```
docker-compose run service
```

gives me the prompt you expect.

Comment: Updated the original post, hopefully its clearer. After I spin the container up, I wanted to visit Docker Desktop > Running container's terminal and expect that the terminal is in `root@docker-desktop:/playwright#` state instead of just `#`. Though as per @larsks, this don't seem to be posssible.